# How to extract values meeting a certain criterion

Tags: r, extract, criteria

If you have a data frame, e.g.:

```
 D1 <-(DW$Ag, DW$Al, DW$As, DW$Ba)
```

*concentrations of elements

And you run a `shapiro.test`
and the results are, e.g.:

```
             DW.Ag      DW.Al        DW.As     DW.Ba      
statistic 0.9030996  0.5204454    0.9761229 0.9286749  
p.value   0.01000898 8.873327e-09 0.7157865 0.04528581
```

and you need to extract all p-values equal or below 0.5, how do you do it?
I tried:

```
stat[stat$p.value <= 0.5, ]
stat[which(lres1$p.value <= 0.5), ]
```

(note: let's say the name of the results was STAT/list containing data..

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to extract the columns where the p.value is below .05?  Or just a named vector of the p.values that are below .05?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick read of the help page for the shapiro test indicates that the object returned is a list item containing several objects, including the p-values.

```
str(shapiro.test(rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 3)))
```

So if you were to run the shapiro test on multiple columns of numeric data like:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 3), x2 = rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 3), x3 = rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 3), x4 = rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 3))
list <- lapply(df, shapiro.test)
```

And inspect the results using `str()`. You would find the p-values for the 4 test run on this sample data.

[str](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyYkW.png)

Extract them out using some looping code, and you are good to go

```
x <- unlist(lapply(list, `[`, 'p.value'))
x[x <= 0.5]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok - great! that was helpful - Did not think about it that way.
have a nice day!